# Explain to understand this code

Tags: javascript, function

Please Help me to understand this code.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Comment: See [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). At the end of the article, there's a polyfill for browsers not supporting this method. Your code is a simplified Object.create polyfill.

Comment: This is checking if `Object.create` is available and if not available its defining it as a function. Inside it, its creating a new function and setting original object as its prototype

Comment: thanks for your help #rajesh